# How to implement wcf callback functionality in flex client

Tags: apache-flex

I want to send notification from wcf to flex client, how to do as flex client only provides client socket functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to write it for your own. In a way or another you need first to create a subscriber somewhere. Flex is open source.